Как изменить сочетания клавиш Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V, Ctrl + X, Ctrl + Z на ubuntu 24.04?
Хочу изменить сочетания указанных клавиш чтобы вместо Ctrl использовать Alt, нашёл в настройках нужный раздел, но нужных сочетаний найти не могу. Подскажите, как изменить, пожалуйста.


В настройках системные сочетания клавиш изменить нельзя.

https://pingvinus.ru/note/ubuntu-change-layout-hotkeys
незнаю, читали вы или нет, но тут ответ на ворпос и различные пути его решения к тому же(цитирую один из вариантов):

Смена сочетания клавиш через утилиту Gnome Tweaks
Если у вас не установлена утилита Gnome Tweaks, то ее нужно сначала установить. Это можно сделать через штатный Менеджер приложений Ubuntu, используя поиск по фразе "gnome tweaks". На русском языке приложение переведено как "Доп. настройки GNOME".


Также можно установить Gnome Tweaks через терминал. Откройте терминал (для этого можно нажать сочетание клавиш Ctrl+Alt+T). Выполните команду:


sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
Запустите утилиту Gnome Tweaks. Запустить можно из Лаунчера (иконка "Доп. настрой...").


Выберите вкладку Клавиатура и мышь и нажмите кнопку Дополнительные параметры раскладки


Откроется окно с разворачивающимся списком настроек комбинаций клавиш. Найдите пункт Переключение на другую раскладку. Установите галочку напротив сочетания, которое вы хотите использовать для переключение раскладки клавиатуры.

